# Multiprocessing doesn't make script faster

Tags: python

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to make my script run faster but it doesn't seem to have an affect on the runtime. My script takes in a 100 length list of IDs and with multiprocessing returns a dictionary where each ID holds a dataframe. This is what my code looks like:

```
def worker(id, return_dict):
    df = some_func(id)
    return_dict[id] = df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    id_list = ** list of 100 IDs **
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for id in id_list:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(id, return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
```

Is there a way I can get this process to run faster?

Comment: I'm unclear why you're using dict for parameter passing.  Why not use a return function and then compile into an aggregate result at the end.  Also...keep as numpy arrays if your data is numeric until the very last step.  Panda processing is slow.

Comment: Multiprocessing only helps if the jobs are bottlenecked by something that benefits from parallelization (e.g. CPU resources on a multi-CPU machine, or latency from network requests that can be made in parallel).  In some cases it can actually hurt -- for example if the jobs are all I/O bound accessing different files on the same disk, parallelization might eliminate benefits you'd otherwise get from data locality by forcing the disk to jump around between files accessed by the different jobs.  What exactly does `some_func` do?

Comment: With a single processor available, Multiprocessing will speed you up only you have I/O bound tasks.  For compute bound tasks you need to be able to distribute the tasks among several processors/cores.

Comment: Avoid naming things that override built-ins. You are overriding `dict`

PEP8 - https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/
`single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword`